# Most efficient configuration of C# Tasks and Continuations when calling a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I am creating a network client that talks to a real-time web API.

The client must make many different calls per second and feed a `Task<TResult>` back to each client component so the client can decide whether to block:

```
public Task<TResult> Execute<TResult>(IOperation<TResult> operation);
```

The process of making an API call runs like this:

1. Serialize the (small, less than 1KB) request to Json
2. Send the request using an `HttpClient`
3. On success, deserialize to `TResult` (Json could be a few hundred KB in size, but usually much smaller) and return

In my tests, choosing where to include each step within a Task workflow (and therefore on which thread) has a significant impact on the performance.

The fastest setup I have found so far is this (semi-pseudo-code, omitted generic type params for brevity):

```
// serialize on main thread
var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
// create message - omitted
var post = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.client.SendAsync(requestMessage)).Unwrap();
return post.ContinueWith(response =>
            {
                var jsonString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString.Result);
            });
```

The slowest is this setup where the whole process is executed within a single task:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew((request) => 
            {
                var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
                // create message - omitted
                var post = client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                var jsonString = post.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString.Result);
            })
```

I would have thought the last method could be quickest because you create one background thread per request. My assumption is that this doesn't allow the TPL to make the most efficient use of the available threads because of the blocking call.

So, is there a general rule around what should go in a task and what should sit outside it, or in a continuation?

In this specific case, are there any further optimisations I could try?

Comment: how did you benchmark this, im curious did you use 1 request or multiple to benchmark. Because `ContinueWith` allows you to start processing the response of one request while another request is being sent out.

Comment: Could you provide stats on why you say one is more performant than another? For what you are doing, I would just do the single task approach. At least, if blocking is what you are trying to get rid of?

Comment: I used multiple requests - batches of 10. I don't want to anger the Api!

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` at all, as `SendAsync` returns a `Task` already:

```
var post = this.client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
return post.ContinueWith(response =>
        {
            var jsonString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString.Result);
        });
```

This will actually be more efficient, as it doesn't require a ThreadPool thread at all.

Note that you could further optimize this with `async`/`await` (to keep the response asynchronous):

```
var response = await this.client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

This could be written via TPL continuations, as well, but this would require returning the (unwrapped) Task from `ReadAsStringAsync`, then posting a new continuation on it in order to get the final string.

Comment: can you explain why this doesn't require a ThreadPool thread? does't SendAsync use a thread pool?

Comment: @StanR. No - SendAsync uses asynchronous IO and doesn't tie up a TP thread.  It does use a ThreadPool IO thread when the signal is raised to run the continuation/events/etc.

Answer (score 2):

So, first off, there's no reason to use `StartNew` when sending the initial request.  You already have a task, it's needless overhead to start the task in a background thread.

So this:

```
var post = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.client.SendAsync(requestMessage)).Unwrap();
```

Can become:

```
var post = this.client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Next, in both cases, you're blocking on the results of the `ReadAsStringAsync` method, rather than processing it asynchronously.  This is chewing up another thread pool thread just sitting there doing nothing.

Instead do something like:

```
return post.ContinueWith(response =>
    {
        return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            .ContinueWith(t => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(t.Result));
    }).UnWrap();
```

Comment: But if the response is small does the overhead of scheduling the ReadAsStringAsync on yet another thread, outweigh the cost of blocking on this instead?

Comment: @MalcomTucker That's going to depend somewhat on whether or not you have enough users to saturate the thread pool or not.  If you don't have enough work that each thread pool thread is doing something then blocking may be quicker, but it won't scale up well with demand, unlike an asynchronous model.